# Angular 2 - DI not working

Tags: angular, typescript

I created 2 implementations for an interface and provided those implementations as providers for two different components. I get this error Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ChildComponent: (?).

Where am I doing it wrong?

```js
interface MyInterface {
    log(msg: string): void
}

class DebugService implements MyInterface {
    public log(msg:string) {
        console.debug(msg);
    }
}

class ErrorService implements MyInterface {
    public log(msg: string) {
        console.error(msg);
    }
}


import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<div (click)="log()">Root Component</div><my-child></my-child><my-child></my-child>' //app/app.component.html
    , providers: [DebugService]
})
export class AppComponent {
    private dummy: MyInterface;
    constructor(d: MyInterface) {
        this.dummy = d;
    }
    log() {
        this.dummy.log("Root");
    }
}


@Component({
    selector: 'my-child',
    template: `<h4 (click)="log()"> Hello Child</h4>`,
    providers: [ErrorService]
})
export class ChildComponent {
    private dummy: MyInterface;
    constructor(d: MyInterface) {
        this.dummy = d;
    }
    log() {
        this.dummy.log("Child");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To use Dependency Injection, you need to mark the services with the @Injectable decorator. Also, you won't be able to inject the interface, you'll need to inject the class you've provided.

```
@Injectable()
class ErrorService implements MyInterface {
    public log(msg: string) {
        console.error(msg);
    }
}
@Component({
    selector: 'my-child',
    template: `<h4 (click)="log()"> Hello Child</h4>`,
    providers: [ErrorService]
})
export class ChildComponent {
    constructor(private dummy: ErrorService) {}
    log() {
        this.dummy.log("Child");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Angular website](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html), "The interfaces are optional for JavaScript and Typescript developers from a purely technical perspective. The JavaScript language doesn't have interfaces. Angular can't see TypeScript interfaces at runtime because they disappear from the transpiled JavaScript."

For this very reason, we cannot use an interface to request a concrete implementation.

@Injectable() is not a required decorator for DI to work. It is adorned on a service class only if that service depends on some other service.

Comment: This is not correct. @Injectable() *is* required for DI to work, as it says in the [@angular documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#injectable): _"@Injectable() marks a class as available to an injector for instantiation. Generally speaking, an injector will report an error when trying to instantiate a class that is not marked as @Injectable()."_

Comment: @nickspoon - an abstract from the documentation link you provided, "We recommend adding Injectable() to every service class, even those that don't have dependencies and, therefore, do not technically require it." Injectable decorator is only required if a service has a dependency on other service. The Angular documentation clearly says that it is not required but it is a "convention" to adorn service classes with Injectable() even if there is no dependency for a service class.

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right, I just tested and a service with no dependencies can be injected without `@Injectable()`. So the answer to your question was that you needed to inject your concrete service, as I said in my answer, and using `@Injectable()` in this instance is just a best practice, not required to make your example work.